# PHP returning less results than phpmyadmin even though the query is the same

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run the following query in phpmyadmin, I get back 18 results - all of which are correct and what I'm looking for.  However, when I copy & paste the query into a php file and run the page, I get back 17 results.

```sql
SELECT 
    ta.jobTaskID, 
    jt.customTaskTitle, jt.taskID, jt.status, 
    d.dealershipName, 
    j.jobNumber, j.jobID, j.title, j.jobSpec,
    wt.taskName, 
    po.dueToProduction
FROM taskassignments ta 
INNER JOIN jobTasks jt ON ta.jobTaskID = jt.jobTaskID
INNER JOIN jobs j ON jt.jobID = j.jobID
INNER JOIN dealerships d ON j.dealershipID = d.dealershipID
LEFT JOIN workflowtasks wt ON jt.taskID = wt.taskID
LEFT JOIN purchaseorders po ON j.jobID = po.jobID
WHERE ta.userID = 1 AND jt.status != 'Completed';
```

EDIT: [Here's a snapshot of my phpmyadmin result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twz2W.jpg)
and [here's a snapshot of my var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn0GN.jpg).

Here's my PHP code (I use a DB class I created)

```
$myTasks = $connection->runQuery("
SELECT 
    ta.jobTaskID, 
    jt.customTaskTitle, jt.taskID, jt.status, 
    d.dealershipName, 
    j.jobNumber, j.jobID, j.title, j.jobSpec,
    wt.taskName, 
    po.dueToProduction
FROM taskassignments ta 
INNER JOIN jobTasks jt ON ta.jobTaskID = jt.jobTaskID
INNER JOIN jobs j ON jt.jobID = j.jobID
INNER JOIN dealerships d ON j.dealershipID = d.dealershipID
LEFT JOIN workflowtasks wt ON jt.taskID = wt.taskID
LEFT JOIN purchaseorders po ON j.jobID = po.jobID
WHERE ta.userID = " . $userID . " AND jt.status != 'Completed'");
```

Finally, here's the code the connection class uses to run a query:

```
// runs the user defined query
public function runQuery($runMe)
{
    $outArray = array();
    if ($this->checkConnection()) // if the connection is a resource
    {
        $returned = mysql_query($runMe, $this->dbConnection);
        if ($returned === false) // if there was an error during sql execution
        {
            echo "SQL Query error: " . mysql_error();
        }

        if ($returned === true) // if a update, insert, delete, etc... command was run
            return true;
        if (is_resource($returned)) 
        {
            $outArray = array(); // returned array with query results
            for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($returned); $i++)
            {
                $outArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($returned);
            }
        }
        if (count($outArray) < 1)
            return null;
        else
            return $outArray;
    }
        else
            echo "Your Database Connection Was Unable To Be Authenticated.";
    }
```

Comment: Please show your PHP code.

Comment: show your php code, you're probably dropping a row somewhere. e.g. doing `$row = fetch(); while(...) { $row = fetch(); print $row; }`

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is not to use `mysql_num_rows()` *at all*, but simply to keep calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` repeatedly until it stops returning results:

```
$outArray = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($returned) ) {
    $outArray[] = $row;
}
```

(Ps. Just so you know, the [original PHP mysql API](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), which your code is using, is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in some future version.  You really should move to [one of the supported APIs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).)

Comment: Gave me back the same results i was getting before... 1 less than what I needed.

Comment: @Brds: Then your PHP query is indeed returning only 17 results. If the SQL text is exactly identical, then the difference must be somewhere else. Are you sure you're running both queries against the same tables in the same database with the same user? (The reason I ask, in particular, is that the missing row appears to be a test record. Maybe your PHPMyAdmin query is running against a test copy of your database, while the PHP code is accessing the production database directly?)

Comment: It seems that the disconnect is SOMEWHERE in the db class.  I ended up running the query with mysql_query() and it worked just fine.  Although looking the class, I can't find anything different.

Comment: Assigning to the array directly (`$outArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc...`) will add a value of `false` to the end of the array.

Comment: @mcrumley: Thanks for pointing that out. I should've tested that before I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($returned); $i++)
```

With:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($returned) + 1; $i++)
```

Comment: you could use <= for comparsion instead of increasing the cound and etc. it is easier

Comment: When i do this, i'm getting the correct number of entries back, but the last one is always "False".  It's also messing up other pieces of the site where the connection class is used... I.E. - My database driven navigation items have an extra (false) item at the end of them.

Comment: Also, mysql_num_rows returns the number of items... so lets say there are 10 items being sent back... my statement is saying "$i < 10"... which would then go from 0 to 9... which is correct.  Doing "$i <= 10" would be looking for an element that's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Your last row is being skipped because you are only checking to see if `$i` is less than  `mysql_num_rows($returned)`. Where you should be checking to see if it is less than or equal to.

So you will need to change the following line:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($returned); $i++)
```

to

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= mysql_num_rows($returned); $i++)
```

And then you will get all your data returned to your PHP as you would expect.

Comment: Last item is now False... although the correct number of items are being returned.

Comment: mysql_num_rows returns the number of items... so lets say there are 10 items being sent back... my statement is saying "$i < 10"... which would then go from 0 to 9... which is correct.  Doing "$i <= 10" would be looking for an element that's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear all array used inside the loop by calling unset function after the loop to clear all array like

```
while(){
//your code
}
unset(array);
```

This will solve your problem as it solved mine.